# Json string format is not getting in required format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call an api by passing json string and I am getting an error "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
The json string that I suppose to pass in the following format

```
[{"unit_id":null,"unit_code":"m","unit_name":"meter",audit_user_id":None,"audit_ts":null},[]]
```

it will add extra brackets in the begin and end while I convert to json. The result will look like this.

```
{[{"unit_id":null,"unit_code":"m","unit_name":"meter",audit_user_id":None,"audit_ts":null},[]]}
```

so how can I pass the json without these opening and closing brackets?. Or should use some array?

Comment: Please send descriptive code

Comment: How do you kn ow this is Json parsing issue, mostly this is some exception at the server, nothing to do with Json

Comment: is it possible to include the code that you are using to generate the JSON data

Comment: Your initial Json is not correct, check the following:
`[{"unit_id":null,"unit_code":"m","unit_name":"meter","audit_user_id":null,"audit_ts":null},[]]`

Comment: Or may be: (Did not replace None by Null)

`[{"unit_id":null,"unit_code":"m","unit_name":"meter","audit_user_id":"None","audit_ts":null},[]]`

Comment: Finally I found the answer. Thank you for the valuable support. I used ,

    var JSONString = new StringBuilder();

Comment: string str = "{'unit_id':null,'unit_code':'" + Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[i]["unit"]) + "','unit_name':'" + Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[i]["unit"]) + "','audit_user_id':null,'audit_ts':null}";
                            JSONString.Append("[");
                            JSONString.Append(str);
                            JSONString.Append(",[]]");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are getting "Internal Server Error" with status 500 which clearly mean your call will not get hit proper function it may be possible you have trouble with function name of parameters (In your's case its due to parameters).

To send Json you must parse your parameter in JSON format.

Here is the code for that

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(yourString);
```

Pass this "data" variable in parameters for API.

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Did you check if its a valid Json ?

Comment: what is the namespace of JObject?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing starting double-quotes on 'audit_user_id' property also the value of this property is not inside double-quotes.

It should be like this:
"audit_user_id":"None"

Please try below code: `[{"unit_id":null,"unit_code":"m","unit_name":"meter","audit_user_id":"None","audit_ts":null},[]]`

Answer (score 0):

You Json seems to be incorrect. Please correct it. You are missing double quotes and using commas not at right places. I have modified json.

```
[{
    "unit_id": null,
    "unit_code": "m",
    "unit_name": "meter",
    "audit_user_id": "None",
    "audit_ts": "null"
},
[]
]
```